# What is the benefit or use-cases of adding android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in Android system application?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-source

I am building a system application for custom ROM. I have access to AOSP and can customize and build the source code with the application apk.

I have read for a application to be a system app we need to add android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in the manifest tag of AndroidManifest file.

I want to know what is the benefit or use-case if I add it or don't add it?

Also this seems to be deprecated in Android=29. Is there any alternative for it? (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid)

Thanks